# CS50 Speller - Check function stops working after finding first 4 misspelled words

Tags: c, cs50

I am working on problem set 5 in CS50x2022: speller. After some time I finally managed to make my code somehow "work properly". the `check` function does work at start but after finding a few misspelled words it stops. Debug50 shows the error "Unknown stopping event". What can be the source of that?

```
bool check(const char *word)
{
    node *cursor = malloc(sizeof(node));
    int hash_word = hash(word);
    cursor->next = table[hash_word]->next;
    while (cursor->next != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(word, cursor->next->word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
           cursor = cursor->next;
        }
    }
    free(cursor);
    return false;
}
```

Here is my load function since there might be the source of the problem? But as I checked, it loaded every word from a dictionary right, but in case here it is.

```
// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    for (int z = 0; z < N; z++)
    {
        table[z] = malloc(sizeof(node));
        table[z]->next = NULL;
    }
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 143091; i++) //143091
    {
        number_of_words = number_of_words + 1;
        char word[LENGTH + 1];
        fscanf(file, "%s", word);
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        strcpy(n->word, word);
        int number = hash(n->word);
        n->next = table[number]->next;
        table[number]->next = n;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: @Marcis -  When formatting the code I saw that the first function appeared to have one extra closing `}` at the end.  I removed it.   Please double check that it really did not belong, and replace it if necessary.

Comment: @ryyker Thanks and sorry, i will make sure to write the post more properly next time.

Comment: An extra safety precaution: In `hash`, (e.g.) if you did: `return n;` then change that to `return n % N;` to prevent `table[number]` from going beyond the end

Comment: `load` returns a truthy value (`1`, `true`) regardless of what happens, and does not always close the file. `check` doesn't always free the allocation, and the value of `cursor` can change throughout the function, so `free(cursor)` may not always target the original allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason for the `check` function to allocate memory. It should just iterate on the list pointed to by the hash table entry.

Furthermore you test each entry pointed to by `cursor`, not `cursor->next`.

Here is a modified version:

```
bool check(const char *word) {
    int hash_word = hash(word);
    node *cursor = table[hash_word]
    while (cursor != NULL) {
        if (strcasecmp(word, cursor->word) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Loading the dictionary is incorrect too:

- do not allocate a dummy node for each entry in the hash table, just initialize the array with null pointers.
- don't make an assumption about the number of words.
- do test for `fscanf()` successful conversions.
- avoid potential buffer overflows by tell `fscanf()` the maximum number of characters to store into the destination array.
- return `false` in case of error and close the file.

```
// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary) {
    number_of_words = 0;
    for (int z = 0; z < N; z++) {
        table[z] = NULL;
    }
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    char word[64 + 1];
    // read all words from the dictionary.
    // no assumption on the number of words
    while (fscanf(file, "%64s", word) == 1) {
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL) {
            fclose(file);
            return false;
        }
        strcpy(n->word, word);
        int key = hash(n->word);
        n->next = table[key];
        table[key] = n;
        number_of_words += 1;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think at the begining i did the first pointers right way but since program wouldn't compile i made all the stupid, unnaceserry memory allocation and those weird **cursor->next** to make a program compile. Thanks for pointing it out, after checking your **check** function i was able to clean the whole program and finally make it work right! Hope it doesn't count as that much cheating, but i just couldnt figure it myself since the program was somehow... working, partly :)

Comment: @Marcis: No cheating at all:) Learning from your mistakes is a good way to progress... To learn C, one must write programs and it does require constant attention and hard work to make them function reliably and efficiently.